# Xquery can't access XML HTTP content as XML document

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In HTTP POST requests, I am getting simple XML like this:

```
<createcoll>
  <title>some foo title</title>
  <editor>foouser1</editor>
  <editor>foouser2</editor>
  <editor/>
  <indexer>foouser3</indexer>
  <indexer>foouser4</indexer>
  <indexer/>
</createcoll>
```

In eXist-db I have an xquery module which examines the request, extracts the content, and then must transform it into a document to be stored on the server.

Getting the content works without a problem:

```
let $content := request:get-data()
```

And I can store it directly on the server:

```
let $store := xmldb:store("/db/apps/myapp/data","foodoc.xml",$content)
```

And once it is stored I can query it like an XML document.

However I need to access `$content` via Xquery in order to extract and transform data *before actually storing it*. But, for example, this statement returns nothing:

```
let $editors := $content//editor
return $editors
```

I suspect XQuery doesn't "see" it yet as an XML document? How do I get it to see it as such?

(The document has no namespaces.)

Many thanks.

Comment: Is it possible the data has not been posted with the appropriate Content-Type header? If so, your request handler may be treating it as plain text instead of XML.

Comment: https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/request suggests it should be treated and parsed as XML into an XML document node. Have you run some tests like `$content instance of document-node()` or `$content instance of xs:string`?

Comment: Of course there is the `parse-xml($content)` function in XPath 3 if it is really a string with XML and you want to parse it.

Comment: @wst the headers come across as `contentType: "text/xml"`, `dataType: "xml"`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen `$content instance of document-node()` = true so this becomes more mystifying as the code above (with exception of real data) is exactly as it is in my Xquery.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is check and see if your request body XML is namespaced: `$content//*:editor`

Comment: @wst that is exactly it, thank you! I am transforming _into_ the TEI namespace and it wasn't recognizing nodes that had _no_ namespace. I put in my post that the doc had no namespace, but I was forgetting about the target namespace.

Comment: @jbrehr those are not valid HTTP 1.1 headers!